# A box contains balls of which 10 are white, 5 yellow and 10 black...

Tags: probability

A box contains balls of which 10 are white, 5 yellow and 10 black.
A random ball is chosen from the box and it is observed that it is not black. which is the probability that it is yellow?

**My work:**

Let

$E_1=$"The ball is not black"

$E_2=$"The ball is yellow"

Then,

$P(E_2|E_1)=\frac{1}{3}$

is good this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct, but probably better to include the process:

$$P(E_2\ |\ E_1)=\frac{P(E_2\cap E_1)}{P(E_1)}=\frac{5/25}{(5+10)/25}\ldots$$